# Grab bash script from an storage account and install in a Linux VMSS

Tags: azure-storage, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a bash script in an azure storage account and I want to call that script from an Azure VMSS, when a new version of the script is available. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom Script Extension can be used to run the script in VMSS.

The [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux) downloads and executes scripts on Azure virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment configuration, software installation, or any other configuration or management tasks. Scripts can be downloaded from Azure storage or GitHub, or provided to the Azure portal at extension run time. The Custom Script Extension integrates with Azure Resource Manager templates, and can be run using the Azure CLI, PowerShell, Azure portal, or the Azure Virtual Machine REST API.

It can be called on Virtual Machine Scaleset using [Add-AzVmssExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmssextension?view=azps-6.1.0)

Comment: Again, as I mentioned in your other answer, please stop asking people to upvote/accept your answers. Also, the question here is off-topic: it's essentially a yes/no question and unrelated to programming; maaaaaybe it fits on SuperUser or ServerFault? But without more detail, it's difficult to know. But your answer essentially a link to documentation, and not a specific solution to anything.